# Hotkey to navigate scenes in Blender 2.8?

Tags: interface, workflow, shortcut

In Blender 2.7, i could change the layout with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>.
In 2.7, the scene was layout dependent, allowing me to navigate the scene this way.

However, in Blender 2.8, the layout has become the workspace and works completely independent of the scene.

I didn't find anything other than a mouse click to change the scene.
Do you know how to navigate scenes using keyboard shortcuts in 2.8?

Comment: I guess, one would need to write an addon for this. Only native solution seems to be to open additional Outliner set to Scenes mode to be used as selector (mouse clicks again)

Comment: In Blender 3.0, once you highlight a Scene in outliner, you can toggle between scenes using up and down arrow keys. I know this is not a global hotkey, but it might help someone.

Answer (score -3):

Here's the menu to navigate them:
[image]

Comment: That works for workspace. So that doesn’t help me. I need scene navigation.